# docker build images success but docker images get no image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

#### problem description

I was using docker buildx and docker build commands to build image from a Dockerfile. The build progress is successful, but there is no new images there. the output like something below:

```
...
=> [12/12] COPY ninja /usr/bin                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                            12.1s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                           12.1s
 => => writing image sha256:a836191975ad7dc244a55eb16b440ee58fbb2db11137fa8debe09a6318814635                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => naming to **:**
```

#### environment description:

```
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker App (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3)
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc., v0.8.2-docker)
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc., v2.6.0)
Server:
 Containers: 38
  Running: 17
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 21
 Images: 9
 Server Version: 20.10.17
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: systemd
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 10c12954828e7c7c9b6e0ea9b0c02b01407d3ae1
 runc version: v1.1.2-0-ga916309
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 5.4.0dz-5.4-host-psi+
 Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: aarch64
 CPUs: 64
 Total Memory: 125.4GiB
 Name: sriov-TaiShan-200
 ID: QRDU:B5AB:KFPC:CTM3:HT26:UKGZ:6TDT:WYW4:WAJP:FNMT:2PXP:KHCO
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Username: xiaojueguan
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

#### things I tried

1. I restarted the docker service with below commands, and i get the images

```
systemctl restart docker
```

#### the question I want to know

1. Why this happens
2. Is it ok to get the images with my trying method

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the exact commands you're running?  What's the output of `docker images` after you run the build?

Comment: The Dockerfile is sensitive. So, i can only past very small part above and the output also has a small part above.